# Python, regex - how to match second group, only if first group is matched

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

**Input:**

```
2SASKS6SJSQSOS
```

**Expected Output:**

```
2S AS KS 6S JS QS
```

**My code:**

```
import re

row = input()

pattern = r"([1]?[0-9]?[JQKA]?)([SHDC])"

result = ''

for (first, second) in re.findall(pattern, row):
    if first and second:
        result += first + second + ' '

print(result)
```

So at the moment **it works**, because this check `do the magic`:

```
if first and second:
```

Without this check it return:

```
2S AS KS 6S JS QS S
```

because it matches second group.

**I want to do this in the regex, not with if check, is it possible ? To check if first group is matched, then to match second group?**

Comment: what do you mean first and second? what can first take? what is second supposed to be? are you just splitting into 2??

Comment: Do you want to split into the above pairs ?

Comment: Is group 1 always one character?

Comment: There is simple input and output, I look for solution about this input. Questions about "Is group 1 always one character" are not relevant : )) "Do you want to split into the above pairs ? " - Yes I want, that's why is "expected output"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add a [**lookahead**](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) to make sure there is a digit or a `J`, `Q`, `K` or `A` letter:

```
import re
row = '2SASKS6SJSQSOS'
pattern = r"(?=[0-9JQKA])(1?[0-9]?[JQKA]?)([SHDC])"
result = [x.group() for x in re.finditer(pattern, row)]
print(result) # => ['2S', 'AS', 'KS', '6S', 'JS', 'QS']
```

Or even

```
result = re.findall(r"(?=[0-9JQKA])1?[0-9]?[JQKA]?[SHDC]", row)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Nxyy0s)

It works because the second group pattern is not overlapping with what is matched in the first group.

See the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=(%3F%3D%5B0-9JQKA%5D)1%3F%5B0-9%5D%3F%5BJQKA%5D%3F%5BSHDC%5D):

[image]

**Details**

- `(?=[0-9JQKA])` - a positive lookahead that requires an ASCII digit, `J`, `Q`, `K` or `A` immediately to the right of the current location
- `1?` - an optional `1`
- `[0-9]?` - an optional ASCII digit
- `[JQKA]?` - an optional letter from the character class: `J`, `Q`, `K` or `A`
- `[SHDC]` - an `S`, `H`, `D` or `C` letter.